# Mouse and Keyboard slow and unreactive in ubuntu 15.10

Tags: keyboard, mouse, radeon

I have recently switched to Ubuntu 15.10, because my on-board and was-legacy graphics card won't work perfectly with Unity, so i decided to buy a supported graphics card, so i have bought an XFX Radeon HD 5450 card and have installed it.
Everything is working perfectly, except for my mouse and keyboard!
For example: My mouse becomes very slow some times and when i move it there is a short delay before the pointer actually moves on the screen, or when i'm typing  anything wit the keyboard some keys are not showing up or show up after several seconds. I have tried AMD propietarly (don't know how to spell that correctly) drivers but it didn't work.
Any help?

Thanks,

New User

Comment: To my knowledge there is no 'Ubuntu 15.01' did you mean 15.10?

Comment: yes, i mean 15.10

Comment: is your mouse wireless?

Answer (score 0):

recently I had an experience in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS on a Lenovo Miix700 Tablet and the swapiness. Maybe helps.
I haven't a Swap-Partition so I reduced the swapiness factor to 0 that did the effect:

```
sudo sysctl vm.swappiness=0
```

Then write the swapiness in sysctl.conf:

```
sudo gedit /etc/sysctl.conf
```

adding that line at the end of the file:

```
vm.swappiness=0
```